# Invalid syntax error returned for %matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm experiencing some trouble importing the below libraries displayed within the below markdown, which is required for a Python sentiment analysis via Twitter:

```
# General:
import tweepy           # To consume Twitter's API
import pandas as pd     # To handle data
import numpy as np      # For number computing

# For plotting and visualization:
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib
```

Although somewhat new to Python3/pip, as a Rubyist/elephpant, I'm certainly no stranger to homebrew- after commenting-out `%matplotlib` the file apparently imports all libraries listed except`%matplotlib`, which appears to be [the Jupyter invocation](http://matplotlib.org)- so how do I correctly load the import for `%matplotlib` in standard Python (3.6.2) in order to avoid the below error?  Is there an alternative approach?

```
 File "toolbox.py", line 10
    %matplotlib
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you!

Comment: `%matplotlib` is an [IPython magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=magic#magic-matplotlib).  That's for interactive use.

Comment: Thanks @wim- are you suggesting to just comment out `%matplotlib` or that and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [documentation explains](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html#id1):

> Starting with IPython 5.0 and matplotlib 2.0 you can avoid the use of IPython’s specific magic and use `matplotlib.pyplot.ion()`/`matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()` **which have the advantages of working outside of IPython as well**.

(emphasis mine)

So in your case you could just use:

```
plt.ion()
```

instead of the **bare** `%matplotlib`.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction- I hadn't seen those dox yet- was too focused on [matplotlib dox](http://matplotlib.org/).  Thanks again.